# Why doesn't variable update in for loop JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, for-loop, variables, scope

I am doing a coding challenge where the letters in a string are replaced by their partner letters, I know that there is probably a better way to do this, but I just want to know why this doesn't work. Here is the code:

```
function DNAStrand(dna){
  var strObject = {"A":"T", "T":"A", "C":"G", "G":"C"};
  let newDna = "";
  for (let i=0; i < dna.lenght; i++){
    newDna += strObject[dna[i]];
  }
  return newDna
}
```

the function returns an empty string or "", the value of newDna before the loop, it doesn't change.

Comment: You misspelled "length"

Comment: What string are you passing into the function? And you misspelt "length"

Comment: Nick definitely asked the right question!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
for (let i=0; i < dna.lenght; i++){
```

You made a typo. Change this to `dna.length`.

Comment: Don't post answers to simple typos. Just comment and vote to close.